# UIWebView Paste action add font tag to my html

Tags: ios, uiweb

In my application I have a contentEditable UIWebView.
When I use copy: and then paste: functions, and examine the html generated, i see that the paste code is insterted in a "font tag" that change the appearence of the page.

For example: I copy an h1 tag with some text, when i paste it, and examine the html i see that this h1 tag is inserted in "font" tag that use "Times" and it is resized to "3".

I have examined the UIPasteboard but the code inside it is correct.

How can i solve my issue?
Please, it is very important.

Cheers

Comment: facing same problem have you got solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/13605816) in `UIWebView`. If your `contenteditable` element has no `font-size` style specified, the content is pasted correctly.